# A program that checks if a triangle can be built with the sides of given lengths. How can I shorten the IF conditions?

Tags: go

I wrote a simple GO program to asks the user for three integers (firstNum, secondNum, and thirdNum). I'm using the triangle inequality to determine if a triangle can be built using those three integers:

A (firstNum) + B (secondNum) > C (thirdNum)

A (firstNum) + C (thirdNum) > B (secondNum)

B (secondNum) + C (thirdNum) > A (firstNum)

The program works fine if I use the following IF statement (see below), but the conditions make the statement a bit too long. I know I can also use nested IF statements but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

```
if (firstNum+secondNum > thirdNum) && (firstNum+thirdNum > secondNum) && (secondNum+thirdNum > firstNum) {
    fmt.Println("A triangle can be built")
} else {
    fmt.Println("A triangle can't be built")
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about the line length you could simply split your if statement onto multiple lines to make it more readable:

```golang
if     (firstNum  + secondNum > thirdNum)
    && (firstNum  + thirdNum  > secondNum)
    && (secondNum + thirdNum  > firstNum) {
    fmt.Println("A triangle can be built")
} else {
    fmt.Println("A triangle can't be built")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a great idea. I shortened the variable names. I don't like using single letters as variable names but I think in case of a triangle they would work fine because they reflect the sides.
if (a+b > c) && (a+c > b) && (b+c > a)